# An answer that gave me part of the solution what is correct response?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have finally managed to figure out the issue on stack overflow that I asked. ([PHP Extension for C is failing to find function in C Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772406/php-extension-for-c-is-failing-to-find-function-in-c-library))

There was only one answer and it contained information that got me close to the final solution but not all the way there.  Is the correct action to answer my own question with the full solution, comment or edit the answer that help to contain enough details to outline the full solution or some other option?

Comment: Perhaps you could write an answer on how you solved it whilst at the same time voting up the original answer and posting a thanks comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, of course, entirely up to you. But I would look at it this way...

- If the answer gave you all of the information you needed but just didn't show how it would work with *your exact code* then I would upvote and accept the answer that helped. You could still post your own answer with the code implemented into your own.
- If the answer led you in the right direction but it left you with quite a bit of research to get to the full solution then post your own answer and upvote the other answer, marking yours as accepted. In this situation, I would note in your answer how the other helped you to get to the answer.